# How to use Column Generators in a Table Vaadin 7?

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I have a problem in implementing ColumnGenerator in Vaadin. I am reading the Book of Vaadin, at chapter **5.21.5. Generated Table Columns**, but it seems to be a little bit of lack of instructions in how actually you can implement such functionality.

The book says you need to use generated columns when e.g. you have a column which value is given by values of the other columns, or when you want to format table columns in a particular way, then it makes an incomplete example where only an implementation of a single ColumnGenerator is given without actually showing **how** when this generator is used when rows are added to the table.

So I tried to implement such functionality by myself, here is what I got:

```
    // Generated Table columns
    Table tableWithGeneratedCol = new Table();
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
            "date",     Date.class,   null, "Date",         null, null);
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
            "quantity", Double.class, null, "Quantity (l)", null, null);
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
            "price",    Double.class, null, "Price (e/l)",  null, null);
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
            "total",    Double.class, null, "Total (e)",    null, null);

    tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("date", new DateColumnGenerator());
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("quantity", new ValueColumnGenerator("%.2f l"));
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("price", new PriceColumnGeneretor());
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("total",new TotalColumnGenerator("%.2f e", "quantity", "price"));

    // adding some fake rows
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(), // date column
                                                 new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                 new Double(10),                    // price column
                                                // nothing here                     // total column
                                                }, 1); // itemId
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                 new Double(16.2),                  // quantity column
                                                 new Double(21.2),                  // price column
                                                // nothing here                     // total column
                                                }, 2); // itemId
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                 new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                 new Double(22),                    // price column
                                                 // nothing here                    // total column                                         
                                                }, 3); // itemId
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                 new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                 new Double(20),                    // price column
                                                 // nothing here                    // total column
                                                }, 4); // itemId
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                 new Double(15),                    // quantity column
                                                 new Double(19.12),                 // price column

                                                }, 5); // itemId
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                 new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                 new Double(20.30),                 // price column
                                                // nothing here                 // total column     
                                                }, 6); // itemId
    tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                 new Double(50),                    // quantity column
                                                 new Double(32.89),                 // price column
                                                 // nothing here                    // total column
                                                }, 7); // itemId

    tableWithGeneratedCol.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] {"date", "quantity", "price", "total"});
    tableWithGeneratedCol.setPageLength(tableWithGeneratedCol.size());
    layout.addComponent(tableWithGeneratedCol);
```

This is a snippet from a UI's init() method. As you can see, I create a table with 4 columns, Date, Quantity, Price, and Total (which is given by multiplying Quantity * Price). 
I add some fake rows and for the total column I actually don't add any value because it's value should be determined by quantity and price while the table rows are created (the book doesn't tell how you actually do that, so I am guessing how it should work).

Here are the Table.ColumnGenerator implementations (I use a DateColumnGenerator for the Date column, ValueColumnGenerator for the quantity, PriceColumnGenerator for the price column, TotalColumnGenerator for the total column). So in order:

DateColumnGenerator:

```
public class DateColumnGenerator implements ColumnGenerator {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        Property<?> prop = source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
        if (prop.getType().equals(Date.class)) {
            Date date = (Date) prop.getValue();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
            return new Label(sdf.format(date));
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

ValueColumnGenerator (actually this is the only column generator implementation made by the book):

/** Formats the value in a column containing Double objects. */
class ValueColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String format; /* Format string for the Double values. */

```
/**
 * Creates double value column formatter with the given
 * format string.
 */
public ValueColumnGenerator(String format) {
    this.format = format;
}

/**
 * Generates the cell containing the Double value.
 * The column is irrelevant in this use case.
 */
public Component generateCell(Table source, Object itemId,
                              Object columnId) {
    // Get the object stored in the cell as a property
    Property<?> prop = source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
    if (prop.getType().equals(Double.class)) {
        Label label = new Label(String.format(format, new Object[] { (Double) prop.getValue() }));

        // Set styles for the column: one indicating that it's
        // a value and a more specific one with the column
        // name in it. This assumes that the column name
        // is proper for CSS.
        label.addStyleName("column-type-value");
        label.addStyleName("column-" + (String) columnId);
        return label;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

I have just copied their code. So let's move forward.

PriceColumnGenerator:

```
public class PriceColumnGeneretor implements ColumnGenerator {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        Property<?> prop = source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
        if (prop.getClass().equals(Double.class)) {
            Double price = (Double) prop.getValue();
            String priceStr = String.format("%.2 €", price);
            return new Label(priceStr);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And finally, PriceColumnGenerator:

```
public class TotalColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected String format;
    protected String quantityId;
    protected String priceId;

    public TotalColumnGenerator(String format, String quantityId, String priceId) {
        this.format = format;
        this.quantityId = quantityId;
        this.priceId = priceId;
    }

    @Override
    public Component generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        Double quantity = (Double) source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(this.quantityId).getValue();
        Integer price = (Integer) source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(this.priceId).getValue();
        String res = String.format(this.format, new Double(quantity * price));

        return new Label(res);
    }

}
```

But the result is this beautiful empty table, as you can see from the screenshot:

[image]

Now, how can I actually make this column generators work?

Thank you for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

Don't add properties with the same name as the generated columns.

This should be enough

```
// Generated Table columns
Table tableWithGeneratedCol = new Table();
tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("date", new DateColumnGenerator());
tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("quantity", new ValueColumnGenerator("%.2f l"));
tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("price", new PriceColumnGeneretor());
tableWithGeneratedCol.addGeneratedColumn("total",new TotalColumnGenerator("%.2f e", "quantity", "price"));

// adding some fake rows
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(), // date column
                                             new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                             new Double(10),                    // price column
                                            // nothing here                     // total column
                                            }, 1); // itemId
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                             new Double(16.2),                  // quantity column
                                             new Double(21.2),                  // price column
                                            // nothing here                     // total column
                                            }, 2); // itemId
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                             new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                             new Double(22),                    // price column
                                             // nothing here                    // total column                                         
                                            }, 3); // itemId
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                             new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                             new Double(20),                    // price column
                                             // nothing here                    // total column
                                            }, 4); // itemId
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                             new Double(15),                    // quantity column
                                             new Double(19.12),                 // price column

                                            }, 5); // itemId
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                             new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                             new Double(20.30),                 // price column
                                            // nothing here                 // total column     
                                            }, 6); // itemId
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                             new Double(50),                    // quantity column
                                             new Double(32.89),                 // price column
                                             // nothing here                    // total column
                                            }, 7); // itemId

tableWithGeneratedCol.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] {"date", "quantity", "price", "total"});
tableWithGeneratedCol.setPageLength(tableWithGeneratedCol.size());
layout.addComponent(tableWithGeneratedCol);
```

Comment: Sorry @André, I didn't understand, I do not have properties with the same name... Where are they?

Comment: Ah, you mean that generated columns are separeted from the column properties added with addContainerProperty()? Is it because of this?

Comment: Anyway, I have tried to remove all the `tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty` calls, but I still have an empty table.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with calling method addItem. If you use ColumnGeneretor do not add item into column which is generated by ColumnGenerator. This item must "generate" ColumnGenerator.